# Change Notification Content Extension background color

Tags: ios, notifications, xcode8, ios10

While developing Notification Content Extension I noticed, it's impossible to change background color to clear color.

I want it looks like background of weather standard app widget.

[image]

So, if I change background color of View to clear in IB or by code, it's become white without alpha.

[image]
You see that buttons with blurred background and white notification background looks awful. If you have some ideas, please tell me.
Tested on iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6s iOS 10 beta 3 and Xcode 8 beta 3.

Comment: можно увидеть исходники вашего примера с хабра?

Comment: https://github.com/vani2/Call-Provider-Example @VyachaslavGerchicov

Comment: спасибо, но вываливается куча ошибок

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding a `UIBlurEffect` like this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

blurEffectView.alpha = 0.5;

[self.view insertSubview:blurEffectView atIndex:0];
```

you can play with background color or with `UIBlurEffectStyle` to achieve exact thing that you like.